# Why is "it's" used in the sentence "It's the Visa card people"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

The sentence is from a dialog in Friends where the phone rings, Monica answers it, they want Racheal, and Monica tells Racheal this sentence:

> “It's the Visa card people.”

Is "people" not a collective noun? If yes, shouldn't *they're* be used instead of *it's* here?

Comment: In this case the "it" refers to the person on the other end of the phone line.

Comment: Actually, as Diamond notes, "people" is a collective noun. As such, it is treated like a singular subject, hence the use of "It's" (it _is_) instead of "They're" (they _are_).

Comment: Not at all. The idea of saying "People is" is not in contention. "People" is well and truly plural. The subject of the sentence is "it", not "people". The real question is why you don't say "they are". And the answer is that when you're first identifying someone or something, you say "it". Only by the next sentence can you use the right pronoun: "**It's** the Visa card people. **They** want to speak to you."

Answer (score 6):

The verb ("is") is conjugated based on the subject of the sentence ("it") not the [predicate noun](http://www.glossary.sil.org/term/predicate-noun) ("people").

For example:

- The girls are a team.
- The team is all girls.

Comment: Yes, this is closer to the truth. It has nothing to do with whether you have one person or several on the other hand. You'd also say, "Who's at the door? Oh, it's the boys from across the street!" Or "I see something on the horizon... No, it's five different things!"

Comment: Er... the other end. Anyhow...

Comment: Good explanation, except "people" is technically not an "object" in this sentence. It is called a "[subject complement](http://www.glossary.sil.org/term/subject-complement)" or "[predicate noun](http://www.glossary.sil.org/term/predicate-noun)". This is a bit of a nitpick, but it matters in some contexts. For example, we must say "Who is it?": "*Whom is it?" would be incorrect, even though "whom" can be used for the object of a transitive verb, because "is" is not a transitive verb.

Comment: But you don't say ***this is** apples*; instead, you say ***these** are apples*. Thus, it seems that the subject complement decides what the subject should be. Or *there **are** apples*.

Comment: @Diamond *It* overlaps with *this*, but ultimately their behaviour is not comparable.

Comment: Diamond if you update your question include the "this" issue or ask another question about it, I will update my answer or answer the other question. unless @Luke Sawczak gets there first.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a single person on the phone. So, if you knew them and their name was John you'd say, "It's John." In this case the single person represents a company. You don't know their name (or possibly don't care) and so you refer to them as "Visa card people", but it is still a single person.